# Can't see bootable usb in boot menu

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 and I burned another linux distro to my usb via unetbootin and then I also tried dd comand in console. Problem is I can't see the usb drive in boot menu.. When I tried older usb in which I have burned kubuntu iso from the past i could see it. I also tried to burn iso to different usb but I still can't see it. I think it's a mount problem because it mounts only after I click on it in file manager. Any tips  ?

Answer (score -1):

there is two answers :

1. the usb is damaged via formatting it , so you need to download an usb fix software.
2. the iso file is damaged, check the checksum , and re-download it.

best regards,

Comment: When you write an image to a drive using e.g. `dd`, this overwrites the device, there is no old partition table or formatting left, just the one provided by the image file. And I have no idea what an USB fix software should do.

Comment: Hmm I  figured out its not usb problem maybe iso problem ... it's kali linux iso downloaded from official page , other distros work fine o.O

Comment: check the iso checksum , its better to know if you downloaded a corrupted file or not

Comment: Byte Commander is right , i couldnt say it as he did , of my poor knowledge in english..  you need to fix your partition table, if you are not familiar with doing so , i suggest to download an usb partition fixer tool